# Why there is an undefined offset in this array?

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I want to store some data in an array called `$temp`, but I got an error that there is an undefined offset. Here's my code:

```
$temp    = array();
$terms   = $this->DocumentTerms();
$temp[0] = $terms[0][0];

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($terms); $i++) {

    $flag = true;

    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($terms[$i]); $j++) {

        for ($k = 0; $k < sizeof($temp) || $k < sizeof($terms[$i]); $k++) {

            if ($temp[$k] == $terms[$i][$j]) {

                $flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($flag)
            array_push($temp, $terms[$i][$j]);
    }
}
```

The undefined offset is at this part:

```
if($temp[$k] == $terms[$i][$j])
```

Comment: at which line? what is the error exactly?

Comment: As an aside, any particular reason you chose to use [`sizeof()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) vs [`count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)?

Comment: @summea: `sizeof()` is an alias of `count()`. They're exactly the same.

Comment: @Jason OOO see the update.

Comment: If sizeof($terms[$i])>sizeof($temp), you will try to access an index on $temp that does not exist. See the for loop where you define $k.

Comment: @AmalMurali Ah, I was just curious as to why the OP chose `sizeof()` over `count()` for this code.

Comment: @summea: Ah, okay. Maybe they're from a C(++) background, but that's just a guess :-)

Comment: @AmalMurali I mostly ask because using `count()` can help avoid ambiguity as far as what the `sizeof()` function is actually doing... (as evidenced from the [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) in the [`sizeof()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) function in the docs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conditional:

```
$temp[$k] == $terms[$i][$j]
```

Should be:

```
isset($temp[$k]) && $temp[$k] == $terms[$i][$j]
```

You don't push any data to `$temp` until the end of the second loop, but you try to access the `$k`th index of the array in this conditional.  If it hasn't been set yet, it will fail.  Check to make sure it is set and then continue on with seeing if it equals `$terms[$i][$j]`.

Comment: or `array_key_exists($k,$temp)`

Comment: Yup @JasonOOO, I usually leave that one up to personal preference.  I guess `array_key_exists()` is more obvious as to what you are trying to do, but I like using `isset()` for consistency across the board.  Do you know of any performance differences?

Comment: *+1:* But I wouldn't say `func(condition) && $var = $stuff;` is the best way to write this. It *works*, but I'd expand it to a full statement using the ternary operator.

Comment: Very true @AmalMurali.  I think breaking it up is easiest for explaining what broke and how it is fixed, so I'm going to leave my answer as is.